# Where to get the Google Search XSD

Tags: xml, search, xsd

we are developing an Google search component for our website. We are getting the result from Google in the form of XML.

Where Can I find the XSD for Google search results?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [google xml reference](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/62/xml_reference.html#results_xml_dtd), there is a section about the DTD and its location:

> The DTD is available on the Google Search Appliance at `http://<appliance_hostname>/google.dtd`.

So, it appears that Google use DTDs and not XSDs.

Comment: Yes That is the DTD, but i need XSD and it XMLBeans Requir XSD and also I tried the online tool http://www.hitsw.com/xml_utilites/ to convert the DTD and got the fallowing error. 

An error occurred while trying to convert the XML DTD file to an XML Schema file.
Error details: de.tudarmstadt.ito.schemas.dtd.DTDException: Duplicate element type declaration: IMAGE

Comment: @MPH - DTDs are more expressive than XSD, so not all DTDs can be converted. You may have to create your own XSD manually.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

http://www.google.com/cse/docs/resultsxml.html#XML_Results_for_Regular_and_Advanced_Search_Queries

Comment: That is correct, But there is no reference to XSD. I am planning to use XML bean to generate java objects. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) to convert a DTD into a XML Schema (XSD). I just created [this XSD](https://gist.github.com/raw/971416/454cc6bba798b6c20f702a1acc66ee35ad53e79c/google.xsd) for Google's DTD this way. It's a valid XML Schema, but will probably need manual editing in order to be useful.